# Need to restate left side in JS and/or?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a brain cramp here for some reason. Does the left hand side need to be repeated when using `AND/OR` on the same property?

For example, is this fine:

```
if(name === 'Bob' || 'Bill')
```

or is this the correct way:

```
if(name === 'Bob' || name === 'Bill')
```

Comment: `if(name === 'Bob' || name === 'Bill')` is the correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to compare between two the second one is correct

```
name === 'Bob' || name === 'Bill'
```

Above checks if `name` is equal to `Bob` or `name` is equal  to `Bill` return `true`

While this one

```
name === 'Bob' || 'Bill'
```

Above says if `name` is equal to `Bob` return `true` otherwise return `Bill`.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is correct if you want to check for equality of both names with `name`, though I'd prefer the following

```
if (~['Bob','Bill'].indexOf(name)) {}
```

as its a little shorter and easier to extend.